# UTF-32, why is it taking up 8 bytes?

Tags: utf-32

I have been reading all about Unicode lately, because it's pretty interesting how it all works.

So I've read that `UTF-32` is a fixed 4 bytes. Well, I thought it was odd, when on both my MacBook Airs, when I saved a simple file, with one letter (t) in it, it saved with 8 bytes. This also happened with `UTF-16`, which took up 4 bytes (not as odd though). Anyone know why?

> Note: I did check, there's no white space in it

Answer (score 4):

There is most likely a UTF [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) being saved at the beginning of the file in front of the `t` character.  A BOM is used to specify which UTF encoding is being used to encode the file, and in the case of UTF-16 and UTF-32 which endian is being used.

UTF-16LE: BOM (2 bytes) + `t` (2 bytes) = 4 bytes
`FF FE` `74 00`

UTF-16BE: BOM (2 bytes) + `t` (2 bytes) = 4 bytes
`FE FF` `00 74`

UTF-32LE: BOM (4 bytes) + `t` (4 bytes) = 8 bytes
`FF FE 00 00` `74 00 00 00`

UTF-32BE: BOM (4 bytes) + `t` (4 bytes) = 8 bytes
`00 00 FE FF` `00 00 00 74`

Comment: Or maybe **EOF** at the end ?

Comment: Nobody writes an actual EOF character in a text file.  EOF is used by consoles and network protocols.  But to be sure, use a **hex editor** to view the actual bytes of the file.

Comment: So why doesn't my UTF-8 file have a BOM then?

Comment: Because the Unicode specification discourages (but does not prevent) use of a BOM in UTF-8 text files, mainly for backwards compatibility with apps that can handle ASCII text files but cannot handle BOMs.  UTF-8 was designed to be backwards compatible with ASCII.  See the [UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 & BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) FAQ.  Some text editors have an option to save a UTF-8 file with or without a BOM.

Comment: Dump the file contents with `hexdump -C path-to-file` to see exactly what's in there.